# Geolocation module - how to call abstract class method properly

Tags: php, geolocation, drupal-8, drupal-9

I'm using the custom module in my project, and it was working fine with `Geolocation 1.11` module.

After I've updated `Geolocation` to 3.7 my custom module stopped working.

What I've found - my custom module was using trait from 'GoogleMapsDisplayTrait.php' and now it is missing in `Geolocation`. It was like that

```
class LocationsMapBlock extends BlockBase {  

  use GoogleMapsDisplayTrait;

  public function build() {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'locations_map',
      '#attached' => [
        'library' => ['location/map'],
        'drupalSettings' => [
          'geolocation' => [
            'google_map_url' => $this->getGoogleMapsApiUrl(),
          ],
          'locations' => $this->getLocationMapData(),
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }
}
```

I've found that now most similar class to trait `GoogleMapsDisplayTrait`) is inside `geolocation_google_maps` submodule of `geolocation` module.

But now it's not a trait, but abstract class with the same methods as previous trait was.

```
abstract class GoogleMapsProviderBase extends MapProviderBase {
...
}
```

I've tried to add this class:

```
use Drupal\geolocation_google_maps\GoogleMapsProviderBase;
```

But now I'm receiving the error

'Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\location\Plugin\Block\LocationsMapBlock::getGoogleMapsApiUrl() in Drupal\location\Plugin\Block\LocationsMapBlock->build() (line 32 of modules/custom/location/src/Plugin/Block/LocationsMapBlock.php).'

My PHP knowledges is to weak to find the solution...

Answer (score 0):

The undefined function **getGoogleMapsApiUrl()** is, maybe the file is missing?

**Check if the file exists:**

```
/modules/geolocation/modules/geolocation_google_maps/src/GoogleMapsProviderBase.php
```

Try to **install and enable** the following modules for a cleaner working with geolocation - **specially for the geolocation_google_maps**:

```
geofield
geolocation_geofield
geolocation_google_maps
```

Try using this call instead of **$this->getGoogleMapsApiUrl()**:

```
Drupal::service('plugin.manager.geolocation.mapprovider')->getMapProvider('google_maps')->getGoogleMapsApiUrl()
```